# add new role to the same cloud service on azure

Tags: python, linux, azure, virtual-machine, role

i tried to add a new role to the same cloud service that has another role but adding failed. the output xml as shown:

```
<RoleName>ahmed-Sate3441</RoleName>
<RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>  
<ConfigurationSets>
   <ConfigurationSet>
     <ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
     <HostName>ahmed-Sate3441</HostName>
     <UserName>ehpcuser</UserName>
     <DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>true</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>
     <SSH>
        <PublicKeys>
           <PublicKey>
              <Fingerprint>MyFingerPrint</Fingerprint>
              <Path>/home/ehpcuser/ehpcazure/keys/mycert.cer</Path>
           </PublicKey>
        </PublicKeys>
       <KeyPairs></KeyPairs>
    </SSH>
 </ConfigurationSet>
 <ConfigurationSet>
   <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
     <InputEndpoints>
       <InputEndpoint><LocalPort>80</LocalPort>
       <Name>HTTP</Name>
       <Port>80</Port>
       <Protocol>tcp</Protocol
       <EnableDirectServerReturn>false</EnableDirectServerReturn>
    </InputEndpoint>
    <InputEndpoint>
      <LocalPort>5000</LocalPort>
      <Name>XML</Name>
      <Port>5000</Port>
      <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
      <EnableDirectServerReturn>false</EnableDirectServerReturn>
      </InputEndpoint>
    <InputEndpoint>
      <LocalPort>22</LocalPort>
      <Name>SSH0</Name>
      <Port>22200</Port>
      <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
      <EnableDirectServerReturn>false</EnableDirectServerReturn>
    </InputEndpoint>
 </InputEndpoints>
 <SubnetNames></SubnetNames>
</ConfigurationSet>
</ConfigurationSets>
<OSVirtualHardDisk> 
   <MediaLink>http://portalvhdshwjjzg846c0dj.blob.core.windows.net/ahmed-sate515/ahmed-Sate3441.vhd</MediaLink>
   <SourceImageName>NFSIMAGE</SourceImageName>
</OSVirtualHardDisk>
<RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>
```

so i output of xml is

```
{'status': u'Failed', 'error': <azure.servicemanagement.OperationError object at 0x150a510>, 'id': u'', 'http_status_code': u'400'}
```

i do not know why adding a new role to an existing deployment get this error !! can anyone help me

Comment: Just verify, you aren't trying to add a IaaS VM to a cloud service that already has a PaaS deployment are you? And what specific API calls are you using to attempt to add this VM to the cloud service?

Comment: first, i create a virtual machine using Azure python API  create_virtual_machine_deployment() so the hosted service has been created with the first machine then i tried to add a new role to the same cloud service of first role to the same existing deployment using add_role "python api" but it failed.

Comment: @AhmedAbdullah My best advice with corporal APIs, is to follow a standard code convention\example\template strictly.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. My mistake was port conflicts; make sure ports 80 and 5000 are not used by any other service.

Comment: make sure the 80 and 5000 is not what ??